# Key error in python/pygame (code was working fine before)

Tags: python, pygame, keyerror

I'm using python 3.12, and keep getting this error message when I try to run my code:

> KeyError: 0
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 2, in 
> SystemError:  returned a result with an exception set

This is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen_width = 500
screen_height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. It is a problem with the system, but not with the code.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix the system problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs on my system and doesn't throw any error. This is an issue with your Pygame perhaps because it's not yet compatible with python 3.12, see [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/).

To resolve your issue, you can downgrade your python version to 3.10 or 3.11.

If the above doesn't work, then you can also see [similar issues reported](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues) for possible solutions and perhaps report yours too. It's a bug with your Pygame and not an error with the code.